# How to create a race condition in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing, race-condition

I want to test some Object's function for thread safety in a race condition. In order to test this I would like to call a function simultaneously from two (or more) different threads. How can I write code that guarantee that the function calls will occur at the same time or at least close enough that it will have the desired effect?

Comment: You really can't.  Sure, you can write code that has a race condition, but that code will have undefined behavior and could do anything including working correctly so you can't tell that you actually have a data race.

Comment: This is a tough problem, because as soon as you do anything that makes two threads act in concert you've introduced synchronization and eliminated the data race. The best you can do is shoot lots of bullets and hope that something hits the target.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping somebody had some trick or idea. I figured the only way of doing it is a shotgun approach and even then its not a guarantee.

Comment: That's the trouble with race conditions. There is no guarantee.

Comment: I spent nearly a year trying to track down a race condition in a banking application I wrote - I would have loved to be able to make that condition reproducable. When I actually identified it, I felt so stupid. But there is no way really of reproducing, testing or guaranteeing this stuff (before anyone says, "short of using Haskell").

Comment: `rc = new RaceCondition();` :)

Comment: Re, "I figured [on] a shotgun approach..." When you fire a shotgun at a paper target, the target space has two dimensions: It's the space of locations on the paper.  When you try to elicit bad behavior from a multi-threaded program, the target space has far more than just two dimensions. They include the name and version of what operating system you are using, and what compiler you used, and what run-time support you are using... If you try it ten million times on your computer, and it never fails, that doesn't prove that it won't fail the first time you try it on somebody else's computer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  That's a good point. Thankfully I have a target platform that will never change for this code so at least my dimensions are constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is hammer heavily at the code and check all the little signs you may get of an issue. If there's a race-condition, you should be able to write code that will eventually trigger it. Consider:

```
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>

int x = 0;

void foo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        x = x - 1;
        assert(x == 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    std::thread t2(foo);

    t.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Everywhere I test it, it asserts pretty quickly. I could then add critical sections until the assert is gone.

But in fact, there's no guarantee that it ever will assert. But I've used this technique repeatedly on large-scale production code. You may just need to hammer at your code for a long while, to be sure.

Comment: `std::this_thread::yield();` between the increment and decrement should make it _drastically_ more likely to trigger though

Answer (score -1):

Have a struct having a field of array of integers of zero, probably 300-500 kB long. Then from two threads, copy two other structs (one having 1s another having 2s) to it, just before some atomic memory issuing barriers(to be sure undefined behavior area has finished, from main thread by checking atomic variable's value).

This should have a high chance of undefined behavior and maybe you could see mixed 1s, 2s (and even 0s?) in it to know it happened.

But when you delete all control stuff such as atomics, then new shape can be also another undefined behavior and behave different.

Answer (score -1):

A great way to do this is by inserting well-timed `sleep` calls. You can use this, for example, to force combinations of events in an order you want to test (Thread 1 does something, then Thread 2 does something, then Thread 1 does something else). A downside is that you have to have an idea of where to put the `sleep` calls. After doing this for a little bit you should start to get a feel it, but some good intuition helps in the beginning.

You may be able to conditionally call `sleep` or hit a breakpoint from a specific thread if you can get a handle to the thread id.

Also, I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio and (I think) GDB allow you to freeze some threads and/or run specific ones.